# Not able to open one particular site

Tags: 14.04, internet, websites, github

I am not able to open [github](https://www.github.com/). I can access to all other sites but not this one. I got to know that its only I cannot open this as the site is working fine on my friends laptop on other networks.

What could be the problem and how could I resolve it? I am using Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Maybe your boss blocked it? Or are you at home, on your own network?

Comment: I am working on home network.

Comment: What error are you getting? 404? 405? Did you check /etc/hosts,  firewall settings, router for any reference to github?

Comment: I am getting "Server not found" on firefox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have a problem going on with whatever DNS servers you are using. These can either be changed in the router (globally for all machines), or in Ubuntu.

To do to in ubuntu go to network manager and edit connections. Select the connection that you use and select edit. Got to the IPV4 settings section and under DNS try to use googles (as a test)

```
 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4
```

Then disable and re-enable your network and try again.

Comment: Thanks. Also, these are google DNS servers I provided. There are many other available out there to use if you don't want to use google.

Comment: +1 @vinayawsm Another good option is [OpenDNS](https://www.opendns.com/home-internet-security/opendns-ip-addresses/). It's *probably* NSA-free. Probably.

Comment: That's the one I was trying to think of but couldn't. I got 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4 burned into my brain